# Combine and filter multiple RSS feeds?

Tags: rss, feed

I have a list of approx 10 RSS feeds from different websites that I would like to view, using Feedly or something, but I first need to filter these RSS feeds for a specific keyword in the title.

What's the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Yahoo Pipes ( http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) I think it does what you are wanting.

Comment: I've previously used Pipes and it does the trick, but I find it a bit cumbersome. I've started using Dlvr.it to do what I need currently, and its working well.

Answer (score 0):

RSSOwl has a keyword filter option, is this what you are after?
http://www.rssowl.org/dl/videos/keyword/keyword.html

Comment: Not too keen on a desktop app. Thanks for the rec though.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried that specific feature myself, and [its a *little* involved setting it up](http://lifehacker.com/5992404/how-to-build-your-own-syncing-rss-reader-with-tiny-tiny-rss-and-kick-google-reader-to-the-curb) (I'm currently running it off a spare system I have at home, but at the minimum you need php, a web server and a supported DB set up),but I believe [TTRSS](http://ttrss.org) should let you do this. It had various methods of creating RSS feed filters and *any* view available to it can be converted into its own RSS feed (pretty neat, huh?).

In this case I'd probably use the filters function to set tags, view the tag, and create a rss feed based off it.

It also happens to be a great rss client.